# Is RAID6 still redundant during grow?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have a 6-drive RAID6 array which I want to expand to 10 drives. I know how to do this (with `mdadm --add` and `mdadm --grow --raid-devices=10`), but I haven't been able to find information on what happens if there is a disk failure during the operation.

Is the array still redundant against at least one drive failure during a grow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `mdadm` man page:

> When relocating the first few stripes on a RAID5 or RAID6, it is not possible to keep the data on disk completely  consistent  and crash-proof.  To provide the required safety, mdadm disables writes to the array while this "critical section" is reshaped, and takes a backup of the data that is in  that  section.   For  grows,  this backup may be stored in any spare devices that the array has, however it can also be stored in a separate file specified with the --backup-file option, and is required to be specified for shrinks, RAID level changes and layout changes.  If this option is used, and the system does crash during the critical period, the same file must be passed to --assemble to restore the backup and reassemble  the array.  When shrinking rather than growing the array, the reshape is done from the end towards the beginning, so the "critical section" is at the end of the reshape.

Basically, when growing a RAID-6 array, there's a brief period (typically a few seconds) during which there's no redundancy on the RAID devices.  This redundancy can instead be provided by a file stored on a device not part of the array.